# Why i'm getting extra square brackets on my return List in JUnit

Tags: java, list, oop, junit, mockito

I have the ff. test code:

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        RefAccountType refAcctType = new RefAccountType();
        refAcctType.setCode("tax");
        refAcctType.setAccessLevel("1");
        refAcctType.setCreatedBy("anonymous");
        refAcctType.setCreatedDate(new Date(04/18/2018));
        refAcctType.setDescription("taxDesc");
        refAcctType.setEffectiveDate(new Date(04/18/2018));
        refAcctType.setExpiryDate(new Date(04/18/2019));
        refAcctType.setOrderSeq(new BigDecimal(0));
        refAcctType.setStatus("A");
        refAcctType.setUpdatedBy("anonymous1");
        refAcctType.setUpdatedDate(new Date(04/18/2018));
        refAcctType.setVersion("1");

        List<RefAccountType> refAcctTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
        refAcctTypeList.add(refAcctType);

        Mockito.when(refAccountTypeRepository.findAll())
        .thenReturn(refAcctTypeList);

    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {
        List<RefAccountType> refAcctTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
        RefAccountType refAccountType = new RefAccountType( "tax","1", "anonymous", 
        new Date(04/18/2018), "taxDesc",new Date(04/18/2018),
        new Date(04/18/2019),new BigDecimal(0), "A", "anonymous1",  new Date(04/18/2018), "1");

        refAcctTypeList = refAccountTypeService.findAll();
        assertThat(refAcctTypeList).isEqualTo(refAccountType);
        }
```

But i don't know why it returned below error when running the test.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[RefAccountType [code=tax, accessLevel=1, createdBy=anonymous, createdDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, description=taxDesc, effectiveDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, expiryDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, orderSeq=0, status=A, updatedBy=anonymous1, updatedDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, version=1]]> 


but was:<[[RefAccountType [code=tax, accessLevel=1, createdBy=anonymous, createdDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, description=taxDesc, effectiveDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, expiryDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, orderSeq=0, status=A, updatedBy=anonymous1, updatedDate=Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, version=1]]]>
```

I suspect the error is on the extra square brackets.
How can i remove the extra brackets in the beginning and end of the but was result?

Comment: You are comparing a `List<RefAccountType>` with a `RefAccountType`. That is not going to be equal. Maybe you want to compare one of the elements in the list instead.

Answer (score 0):

The extra square brackets indicates that the passed reference was a list of `RefAccountType` objects.  And of course it is not equal to the `RefAccountType` object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just did add refAccountType to a list and then assert the data 1 by 1.

```
List<RefAccountType> refAcctTypeList  = refAccountTypeService.findAll();
refAcctTypeList2.add(refAccountType);

assertThat(refAcctTypeList.get(0).getCode()).isEqualTo(refAcctTypeList2.get(0).getCode());
assertThat(refAcctTypeList.get(0).getAccessLevel()).isEqualTo(refAcctTypeList2.get(0).getAccessLevel());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an object of type `RefAccountType` with a list with type `List<RefAccountType>`.

You should either compare the `RefAccountType` objecs with:

```
assertThat(refAcctTypeList).isNotNull(refAccountType);
assertThat(refAcctTypeList.get(0)).isEqualTo(refAccountType);
```

or with type `List<RefAccountType>`

```
assertThat(refAcctTypeList).isEqualTo(Arrays.asList(refAccountType));
```